# Listening to JS .scroll() efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a scrollable element with many children and a select tag with corresponding options.

I want to change the select's value based on the elements `.scrollTop()`

How to do it efficiently? I thought about storing the children's `.offset().top` in an array and looping throught it. However, the browser doesn't handle it. I might try creating a `.setTimeout()` flag, but that doesn't seem clean.

```
    r = $('ul')
    offsets = []
    r.find('li').each((index) ->
      offsets[index] = $(this).offset().top
    )
    r.bind('scroll', ->
      // while loop checking .scrollTop() > offsets[n] is slow
      // maybe spams to many .scroll events?
    )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about what @osoner said + instead of doing all the calculation in the scroll even handler, you fire another event in the handler after an interval (e.g., 'fooscroll'), and then you have all child elements subscribe to the event, and update themselves depending on conditions you set.

```
var scrollTimer;
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
    if (scrollTimer) { clearTimeout(scrollTimer); }
    scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
       $(window).trigger('fooscroll');
    }, 200);
});

$('li').on('fooscroll', function() {
    // Check scrollTop or whatever...
});
```

Comment: I like this one better (hate `setInterval`). Thanks!

Comment: Am I seeing it right that the event "fooscroll" only gets fired if the user stops scrolling for 200ms?

Comment: @Simon: Yes, you are correct. To clarify, no it doesn't 'throttle' the scrolling. If you want to fire scroll every 200ms instead of only once users has done scrolling, you'd have to do it differently.

Comment: Thank you, sir. The clearTimeout function was exactly what I was looking for, and was the missing piece to my own solution to this problem, which, coincidentally, is very similar to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

You should read [this suggestion from John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/). Basically you set a flag each time user scrolls and do the action you want with an interval function that checks this flag.